# Excel: Choose selected rows from column based on another column's values and display array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in Excel.
Sheet one contains two columns as follows:

column 1:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

column 2:

```
yes
no
no
no
yes
```

On sheet 2, I want to display only one column, which contains the values of column 1, sheet 1, where column 2, sheet 1 is set to "yes".

i.e. I expect the output to be:

```
1
5
```

How can I do this? Can I use INDEX for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
 =FILTER(A1:A5,B1:B5="yes")
```

Just use proper sheet name in case of different sheet.

[image]